# Domino API Plugin - com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

Lotus Designer. Java agent/Script Library. I am trying to add a new dependencies "com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped" in the plugin.xml in the package explorer, but its not available.

I am using version 9.0 without the extension library. Whether these plugins are not available as default? what should be done to get these.

Thanks
Veera

Comment: Isn't it part of *com.ibm.xsp.domino*?

Comment: just an FYI - 9.0 pretty much comes with the "extension libray" built in.  You might not choose to update it with the latest code from OpenNTF.org, but the core ext. library is there.

Answer (score 4):

They're available by default to XPages, not to Java agents. It probably has quite a few dependencies on the XPages Runtime, so many of the dependent plugins probably won't compile into an agent.

com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped is just a wrapper around Domino documents and views to give access to additional properties configurable via the datasource on the XPage. Since the XPage and it's datasource property settings aren't accessible via an agent, there's probably little benefit in using the wrapper rather than the lotus.domino.Document class.